# MySQL - SELECT all from TABLE_1 where id does not exist in two fields of TABLE_2

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a `members` table and a `swipes` table. `swipes` table has two fields `swp_by` and `swp_to`. I want to select all rows from members table where `mem_id` does not exist in `swp_by` and `swp_to`. I have a fiddle set up. In the fiddle please see that currently the query displays both the records. But that should not be the case. The result should only be with `mem_id` `8` here and not `11`. The `swipes` table consists of two records. In 1st record, `swp_by` and `swp_to` both do not have user 1 in it. Hence, only this record should be selected and second one should be discarded.

Current Query

```
SELECT * FROM members
LEFT JOIN swipes ON ((swipes.swp_by = members.mem_id OR swipes.swp_to = members.mem_id))
WHERE swipes.swp_by != 1 AND swipes.swp_to != 1
```

Fiddle Here: [DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5oRZJcAXig5hwCVEHXffN2/0)

Comment: Switch WHERE to AND and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for unmatched rows in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT members.* 
FROM members LEFT JOIN swipes 
ON (swipes.swp_by = members.mem_id OR swipes.swp_to = members.mem_id)
AND (swipes.swp_by = 1 OR swipes.swp_to = 1)
WHERE COALESCE(swipes.swp_by, swipes.swp_to) IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5oRZJcAXig5hwCVEHXffN2/2).
Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM members m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM swipes 
  WHERE m.mem_id IN (swp_by, swp_to) AND 1 IN (swp_by, swp_to)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5oRZJcAXig5hwCVEHXffN2/3).
Results:

```
| mem_id | mem_fname | mem_lname | mem_last_activity   |
| ------ | --------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| 8      | Priyanka  | Jaiswal   | 2020-04-14 23:25:00 |
```

Comment: What does the `COALESCE` do? I mean, what is it's function?

Comment: Yes it is a function that returns the 1st not null of its arguments. Check also my 2nd query.

Comment: Which one out of the two query do you recommend for faster and better performance?

Comment: EXISTS is usually faster because it returns as soon as it finds a mtach.

Comment: Oh is it.. Learnt... Thank you for the lessons :) Also, thank you again for helping me fix my problem :)